# How to change the style of a search bar?

Tags: php, css, search

I'm wanting to change the style of a search bar from the following one:

```
<code><div class="searchbase input-group animated trans" id="searchbase">
    <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e(_l('Searching...'));?>" class="form-control" id="squery" value="<?php _e($querysearch);?>" data-type="<?php _e(vars('g','type')->v);?>" data-bind="<?php _e(vars('g','bind')->v);?>">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-warning searchbutton" type="button" onclick="runsearch()"><?php _e(_l('Search'));?></button>
    </span>
 </div></code>
```

to this one:

http://cssdeck.com/labs/0chmqae2

but cannot figure out how to make it searchable when entering what you want to find. I don't think it's as easy as simply changing the css?

Comment: Why do you think that, when the example you linked to actually uses CSS to accomplish that effect?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Is is styling question or functionality question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking how to integrate your functionality with their styling.

```
<div class="field" id="searchform">
    <input type="text" id="squery" placeholder="<?php _e(_l('Searching...')); ?>" value="<?php _e($querysearch); ?>" data-type="<?php _e(vars('g','type')->v); ?>" data-bind="<?php _e(vars('g','bind')->v); ?>">
    <button type="button" onclick="runsearch()" id="search"><?php _e(_l('Search')); ?></button>
</div>
```

Comment: @BenO'Reilly no problem. If I have solved the problem, could you mark my solution as the accepted answer?

Comment: Done, would you know how to do this too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630231/how-to-place-advertisements-on-each-side-of-a-button